# Xamarin: Close Alert Dialog when back button pressed

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, onbackpressed

I'm new on Xamarin Android. I have a Activity and when the textview is pressed an alert is showed.
The code of AlertDialog is:

```
textView1.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetTitle("title");
                alert.SetMessage("Message");
                alert.SetCancelable(false);
                alert.SetPositiveButton("Cerrar Sesión", delegate { funcCerrarSesion(); });
                alert.SetNegativeButton("Salir", delegate { Finish(); });
                alert.SetNeutralButton("Volver", delegate {  });

                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    alert.Show();
                });
            };
```

I need when the Back Button be pressed, this event close the AlertDialog.
Thank You.

PD: I'm dev on Visual Studio 2012 + Plugin Xamarin

**Editing (ρяσѕρєя K's Solution):**

```
    Dialog dialog;
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
..
textView1.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetTitle("Advertencia");
                alert.SetMessage("Está seguro?");
                alert.SetCancelable(false);
                alert.SetPositiveButton("Cerrar Sesión", delegate { funcCerrarSesion(); });
                alert.SetNegativeButton("Salir", delegate { Finish(); });
                alert.SetNeutralButton("Volver", delegate {  });

                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    dialog = alert.Create();
                    dialog.Show();
                });
            };
...
}

public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            if (dialog != null)
            {
                if (dialog.IsShowing)
                {
                    dialog.Dismiss();
                }
                else
                {
                    base.OnBackPressed();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnBackPressed();
            }
        }
```

This continue showing the alert but when `back button` is pressed, the alert not close.

Answer (score 2):

> I need when the Back Button be pressed, this event close the
>   AlertDialog

To dismiss Dialog on back key press :

**1.** Override `OnBackPressed`.

**2.** Need to access `alert` object in `OnBackPressed` so declare `alert` object before `OnCreate` :

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if (alert !=null){
       if(alert.IsShowing){
          alert.Dismiss ();
        }else{
          base.OnBackPressed();
        }
     }else{
        base.OnBackPressed();
     }
}
```

Comment: `Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder` does not contain a definition for `IsShowing` and no extension method `Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder` could not be found. ( This message appear on `Dismiss` too)

Comment: @KevinF: ok ,Declare `Dialog dialog` before onCreate method and  use `dialog=alert.Create ();dialog.show()` instead of `alert.Show();` on button click

Comment: @KevinF: then use `dialog` instead of `alert` in `OnBackPressed`

Comment: Yes, the back button don't close the alert.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK my event is never getting called if the user only closes the dialog by pressing the backbutton (it works if the user clicks the backbutton after the dialog is closed)